# WSUS causes 32 bit IIS web applications to fail

Tags: iis

On Server : WSUS [Windows Server Update Services] already installed.

I m facing an Issue when i m trying to host my dotnet application on server 2012 with 64 bit, i have set 32bit enable application in application pool but when i run it will give following error.

if i change 32 bit enable application to false then my application work but i need to run with 32 bit enable. Here Is error Code.

HTTP Error 500.19 – Internal Server Error
The requested page cannot be accessed because the related configuration data for the page is invalid. Detailed Error InformationModule DynamicCompressionModule
Notification SendResponse
Handler StaticFile

Most likely causes:
The worker process is unable to read the applicationhost.config or web.config file.
There is malformed XML in the applicationhost.config or web.config file.
The server cannot access the applicationhost.config or web.config file because of incorrect NTFS permissions.
Things you can try:
Look in the event logs for information about why the configuration files are not readable.
Make sure the user identity specified for the application pool, or the authenticated user, has the required permissions to access the web.config file.
Links and More InformationThis error occurs when there is a problem reading the configuration file for the Web server or Web application. In some cases, the event logs may contain more information about what caused this error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is caused by the installation of WSUS on a 64 Bit server which enables Dynamic Compression *globally* in IIS but fails to install a 32Bit version of suscomp.dll on this server.

A 32Bit Application-Pool fails to start because suscomp.dll is not present for 32Bit in %windir%\SYSWOW64\inetsrv\

see [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30301385/1545171) for three possible solutions