# Service not accessible when "Enable 32-Bit Applications" set to true

Tags: web-services, iis-7.5, .net-4.5, windows-server-2008

**On the development server** I use IIS Veresion 7.5.7600.16385

And a Service compiled for .Net 4.5.1, Any CPU

The service works fine on the development server (Win Server 2008 R2).

**On the client's production server** however I get strange problems:

(Same IIS Version, same OS version)

As soon as I set "Enable 32-Bit Applications" the service's **URL is no longer accessible in a browser**. (Page not available)

(I need the 32Bit mode because the service uses some legacy COM components)

What may cause this problems?

Any ideas, hints, suggestions?

---

**Edit**

More Details:

The "IIS Worker Process"  is running as "w3wp.exe *32"

There is a ClickOnce Installation in the same Application Pool which behaves the same: works ok in 64 bit, not accessible if 32Bit set to true.

In fact all pages of this 32Bit App-Pool produce the same behaviour (HTTP 500) page not found.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Step 1: Enable Logging in IIS**

In Order to enable better error messages and log files in IIS you must install two Features:

> Control Panel->Programs and Features->Turn Windows features on or off

You'll need two features installed:

> WebServer->Common Http Features->HTTP Errors
>
> WebServer-> Health an Diagnostics->HTTP Logging

**Step 2: Analyse Error Messages**

With HTTP Errors enabled I got a more verbose message when I accessed any page in the 32Bit App Pool:

> HTTP Error 500.19
>
> DynamicCompressionModule
>
> ErrorCode 0x8007007e

**Step 3: Decode Error Code**

I used [Microsoft Exchange Server Error Code Look-up](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=985) to convert the ErrorCode into something more useful:

> C:\Users\combyte>err 0x8007007e
>
> as an HRESULT: Severity: FAILURE (1), Facility: 0x7, Code 0x7e
>
> ...
>
> ERROR_MOD_NOT_FOUND                                           winerror.h
>
> The specified module could not be found.

It turned out, that a specific DLL was not installed. In my case the installation of WSUS (Windows Server Update Services) installed a 64Bit version of DynamicCompressionModule (C:\Windows\system32\inetsrv\suscomp.dll) only.

**Solution1**

Remove/Disable the XPress compression scheme from the IIS configuration (for all pages/app-pools) using this command:

```
%windir%\system32\inetsrv\appcmd.exe set config -section:system.webServer/httpCompression /-[name='xpress']
```

**Solution2**

Disable loading of the `xpress` module in IIS config file `C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\config\ApplicationHost.config` for 32Bit App-Pools:

add attribute `preCondition="bitness64"` to the xpress module in section `<modules>`:

```
<add name="DynamicCompressionModule" lockItem="true" preCondition="bitness64" />
```

**Solution3**

Install the 32Bit version of `suscomp.dll`(from a 32 Bit Installation of WSUS) into `%windir%\SYSWOW64\inetsrv\`